# How can a simple server load measurement be taken with server side only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for/would like to write a simple load testing script in C# for my server. I would particularly like to measure cpu and memory load (i.e. how little of each are free); I am not concerned about band width.

I guess there methods involving loops and timers but I don't know how Windows Server works - even though it is heavily loaded, the speed at which scripts are run may be unchanged.

I would prefer to keep the bench-marking server side if possible.

I would be very interested to hear from people who have done something similar or who have ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Note: The precision of the reading of cpu and memory load could be as little as red, yellow or green (a traffic light) if that is all that can be done on the server alone.

Comment: Have you checked out Performance Monitor ? It is built-in, configurable and does among other things what you ask for...

Comment: This looks good but I am on a shared server and need to view the results through a page. I cannot run exes myself.

Comment: you don't need to run exes... and: on a shared server anything you measure has no real meaning since those values can be "non-real" because of the virtualization techniques employed for shared hosting!

Comment: You make a good point, I cannot be sure exactly what I am measuring on a shared server - but all I really want is an indication that my allowance of/virtual portion of a server is becoming overloaded/reaching a predefined limit of cpu usage etc - which a performance script would indicate.

Comment: no - the performance script could easily set off a wrong alarm or even not trigger despite having a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

CPU/Memory load and other things can be accessed via different means - for example `System.Diagnostics` and WMI.

Some interesting links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Vista_System_Monitor.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx

BEWARE:

On a shared hosting server anything you measure has no real meaning because of the virtualization techniques employed for shared hosting!